# Name of dropdowlist is renamed automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I've a problem with DropDownlist Name in ASP.NET MVC

In my EditorTemplate, I've

```
  <%: Html.DropDownList("PoolGeometry",Model.selectVm.PoolGeometry, new { id = "poolgeometry" })%>
```

In generate html, I've

```
<select name="Pool.PoolGeometry" id="poolgeometry">
```

Normally, "PoolGeometry" is a field in db. If my dropdownlistname has the same name, selected value is value of field.

I don't understand this automatic rename!

EDIT :

Name is dependent on EditorTemplate :

if EditorTemplate called like this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pool,"SwimmingPool","")%>
```

Name of dropdownlist is "PoolGeometry" and selectedvalues are ok.

But if it is called like this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pool,"SwimmingPool")%>
```

Name of dropdownlist is "Pool.PoolGeometry"